# Accessing Authenticated User's Close/Delete History

Tags: feature-request, api-v2, documentation

I'm working on the PHP chatroom's [cv-pls backlog UI](http://cv-pls.com/backlog). Many users and myself would like the ability to track which questions we have already handled though close/delete votes. To be able to do that I need to be able to look up the current user's close/delete vote history so I can ommit those questions from the display.

According to the docs I can authenticate a user with the following scope:

> **private_info** - access full history of a user's private actions on the site.

However, I see no documentation on what is deemed private and what objects are to be used to access such information? I'm trying to allow my app through an authenticated user to retrieve the user's close/delete vote history. Forgive me if I'm just blind and looking in the wrong place.

- How would it be possible for me to get the close/delete vote history for the authenticated user?

If it's not possible, I would like to make a feature request for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently not possible via the API.  The best you could do is have the user logged into a browser and then screen-scrape the

```
stackoverflow.com/users/{user_id}/?tab=votes
```

pages... Hardly an acceptable workaround.

---

[The *Authentication* doc, *Scope* section](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope), *does* say:

> **private_info** - access full history of a user's private actions
>   on the site.

But what that really means can be seen in the Main API doc page and in the filter edit tool.

On [the **Main API doc page**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), you will see `[auth required]` next to every path that needs authentication; that is, that can see or write a user's "private" data.

These paths currently are just:

- /comments/{id}/delete
- /comments/{id}/edit
- /events
- /inbox
- /inbox/unread
- /notifications
- /notifications/unread
- /posts/{id}/comments/add
- /users/{id}/inbox/me/inbox
- /users/{id}/inbox/unread/me/inbox/unread
- /users/{id}/reputation-history/full/me/reputation-history/full

-- which you can see have nothing that contains close/delete votes.

---

Like wise, [**the Filter Edit Tool**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter), which you can see on almost every path's doc page:

[image: Filter Edit Tool]

Only allows for these objects:

- .wrapper
- filter
- access_token
- account_merge
- answer
- badge
- badge_count
- comment
- error
- event
- inbox_item
- info
- migration_info
- network_user
- notice
- notification
- post
- privilege
- question
- question_timeline
- related_site
- reputation
- reputation_history
- revision
- search_excerpt
- shallow_user
- site
- styling
- suggested_edit
- tag
- tag_score
- tag_synonym
- tag_wiki
- top_tag
- user
- user_timeline
- write_permission

None of which (including `user` and `user_timeline`) return any, user-specific, close or delete-vote information. (limited, Question-specific info is available.)

---

This does seem like a potentially useful feature-request, though.  I'm all for more and better tools for managing the close and delete queues.

Comment: Thanks for the great response as usual! I upvoted and will accept this, but wanting to keep it open for awhile for discussion and to get a dev (Kevin Montrose?) to see it as well.

Comment: You're welcome and good-wishes on getting this feature-request granted.