# /oauth/access_token not redirecting back to my redirect_uri

Tags: bug, api-v2, authentication, php, oauth2

I am trying to implement Stack Exchange using oAuth 2.0. I am able to get CODE but, when I try to get `access_token` through this code:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
?> 
<form method="POST" action="https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="client_secret" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $_GET['code'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="0000" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fmypage.php" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="stack" />
</form>

<a href="https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=0000&client_secret=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&code=<?php echo $_GET['code'];?>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fmypage.php">abcd</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

when I click on anchor tag nothing happens, it just stays on may page only.

When I submit the form, `ACCESS_TOKEN` is displayed on
`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token`
but its not redirecting back to my `redirect_uri`.

If anyone can guide me, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it's broke and not redirecting like [the docs say it should](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).  Coulda swore it worked the last time I checked, but I don't have any active apps that need auth.

Comment: @BrockAdams oh okay , thanks. i need help i am developing on app that needs questions from stack exchange based on a tags. do i need access token for it??

Comment: No, you only need an access token for the eleven paths listed in [this answer](http://stackapps.com/a/4261/7653).  You can read all public information, and you can search, without needing any authentication.