# Can I see my past upvoted questions in handset APP?

Tags: support, feature-request, app-request, ios

It's not hard to dig out questions upvoted by myself through the PC website. But I cannot find any access to them in the ios app. I guess neither does android app. Did I miss something or is it a feature not implemented yet?

Comment: Probably not implemented.  The API (at least the publicly visible part of it) [makes getting your voting history, as a total, very impractical](http://stackapps.com/a/4261/7653).