# Access to my Upvoted Questions

Tags: feature-request, api, voting

I would like to see just my upvoted questions (Don't care about other users as such).

There are some related posts:

- [List of Votes by Authenticated users](https://stackapps.com/q/4725/7653)
- [Can I see my past upvoted questions in handset APP?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4950/can-i-see-my-past-upvoted-questions-in-handset-app)
- [Accessing Authenticated User's Close/Delete History](https://stackapps.com/questions/4260/accessing-authenticated-users-close-delete-history/4261#4261)

But no direct feature requests and the API still doesn't provide this capability.

This will be a very useful piece of information. Specifically, since I make use of it for my personal tracking on interesting and useful questions. And plus I can use this data for my personal tagging and sharing stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Votes by Authenticated users](http://stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users) which says: "Is there any way to filter for questions based on this information?"